# Jquery tab, text inside tab overflow its border in Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui

[image: Image of the overflow]

As you can see from the image, it show the text is overflow the tab border..But upon click the tab, the overflow magically gone.

So basically this problem persist during load and only in chrome..Work flawlessly in firefox and iE

Is There a way to fix this? I spent hours tweaking the css but up to no avail.

**Html**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Draw</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Snapshot</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br>
        <p>containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br>
        <p>containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p><br>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
#tabs{background: none;width:100%;}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        //tabs
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({collapsible: true});

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the related CSS for the area in question?

Comment: @RionWilliams basically there is no specific rules for the tabs, it just use rules from the jquery-ui.css..And i can confirm from firebug that it not inherit any rules from other element

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the width on the tabs themselves, or settings a max-width to ensure they don't exceed their bounds. It could be an issue with inner padding in the parent container and the width of 100% causing it to exceed.

Comment: @you mean adjusting the width of `<div id="tabs">` itself?

Comment: Possibly the CSS for #tabs, try tinkering with it through Chrome's Inspector. It will allow you to change CSS elements and styles on the fly. Try using width: 95% or remove the padding to see if that make a difference.

Comment: @RionWilliams sry im not used to develop on chrome, what you mean chrome inspector is Developer Tools?

Comment: Correct - you should be able to right click and hit Inspect Element...

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? I cannot replicate what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this weird behaviour happening due to the jquery-ui.css i tweaked.